# Prove that the disk $\left\{(x, y)\mid x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\right\}$ is a manifold with boundary.

Tags: manifolds-with-boundary

A manifold with a boundary is a topological space $(X, T)$ whose open sets have continuous one-to-one maps to open sets in half space. Half space is the region of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for which $x^{1} \geq 0$ (in Cartesian coordinates). The topology on half space is the induced topology from the standard one on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

> Prove that the disk $\left\{(x, y)\mid x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1\right\}$ is a manifold with boundary.

Comment: What regularity do you want this manifold structure to have?

Comment: Proposition 5.47 on page 121 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* addresses precisely this type of question. For the function $f\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$, we have that $1$ is a regular value and $$\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\} = f^{-1}\big((-\infty,1]\big),$$so it is a domain with regular boundary. The boundary is $C^\infty$ because so is the function $f$.